# Derive second fundamental from metric

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

If M is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the metric is given by $g=e^{x^2+y^2}(dx^2+dy^2)$. How to calculate Gaussian curvature $K_M$?

First, I use the Gauss equation $K_{\mathbb{R}^2}-K_M=\frac{1}{2}|A|^2$, so $K_M=-\frac{1}{2}|A|^2$. However, I have no idea what should I do next or I need more information on $M$.

edition: M is a curve with parameter $r,\theta$.

I want to know is that

If $F:M\to \mathbb{R}^2$ ,then I know $g_{ii}=\nabla_iF\cdot\nabla_iF=e^r$ and $g_{ij}=0, i\neq j$. Whether these conditions are sufficient to calculate $K_M$ or I should add more illustration on $M$

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Is $M$ immersed in $\mathbb R^3$ instead? Also, if the immersion is not given, it is in general not possible to find the second fundamental form. To calculate $K$, you need **only** the metric. There's a formula for that.

Comment: Um...... what is the Gaussian curvature for a curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the metric is given in a conformal chart, $g= e ^{2 u} (dx^2+dy^2)$, the curvature is $(-\Delta u)e^{-2u}$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplace operator. In your case, $u={x^2+y^2\over 2}$, $K=-e^{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: So the curvature in your answer is derived from Gauss equation? what point of view or reference should I have  to think this question?

Comment: I think the computation of Gaussian curvature in conformal charts is explained in every textbook on  geometry of surfaces . For instance in exercice 1, 2 page 237 in the famous book "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" of Manfredo do Carmo